# Load queries from property file JDBC Java

Tags: jdbc, spring-data-jdbc

So, the case is the following.

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```java
public interface CustomRepo extends CrudRepository<CustomEntity, Long> {    
    @Query(value = "select * from custom")
    public List<CustomEntity> findAll();
}
```

Together with `@EnableJDBCRepositories` in my `@Configuration` file, this allows me to execute the custom query in JDBC natively.

Now, what I need is to substitute that

```
value = "select * from custom"
```

with something like this:

```
value = "query.one"
```

where `"query.one"` is the placeholder for a property in a **.properties** file that looks like this:

```
query.one=select * from custom;
```

How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Do a [custom implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)
2. The alternative is you take a look at the issue for pretty much exactly this: [DATAJDBC-234](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-234) and create a PR for that. If you need help on how to get started feel free to ask in a comment on the issue.

Comment: We're preparing the PR for this, shouldn't be difficult. Thanks!! :D

Comment: Hi! We have the PR ready, we need permission to ask for it. How could we achieve that? What should we do? We're already registered in Jira, but we don't know what else we have to do. :D ...